# TCP implementation in php chat application

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, tcp

Friends, i want to start learning TCP implementation in my php website chat plugin.

I have developed a chat plugin with jquery-ajax, it's tedious task to frequently requesting to database and it's give load to server.

i developed website in CodeIgnitor Framwork.

My Question is :

-> Any library for TCP implementation in php(CodeIgnitor)?
 -> Is it tough task to TCP implementation in PHP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. You certainly don't need a "TCP implementation"; you might be talking about websockets, but it is very unclear.

Comment: lanzz: sorry for such stupid question sir, but i don't have any idea about server response without request. somebody says me about TCP so i asked question about 'TCP implementation in PHP'.

Please give me proper guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to learn `tcp` for making a chat application , what you need is some kind of reverse ajax and websockets , i recommend  node.js and socket.io .

Comment: can you please give some links for tutorail?